# Override style on parts of ComboBox scrollbar

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox, scrollbar

After lots of research, I stumbled across a relatively simple way to target just specific parts of the control style without using the entire control template.  It's partially successful, but I need a little help getting all the way to the end.

Specifically, I am trying to override the Thumb button color of the scrollbar in the dropdown of a ComboBox.  The cool technique I came across is the following, which utilizes nested Style.Resources to access the lower objects...

```
        <Style x:Key="MyComboBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                    <Style.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                            <Style.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="Track">
                                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Cross" />
                                    <Style.Resources>
                                        <Style TargetType="Thumb">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                                        </Style>
                                    </Style.Resources>
                                </Style>
                                <Style TargetType="RepeatButton">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                                </Style>
                            </Style.Resources>
                        </Style>
                    </Style.Resources>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>

        <!--- rest of ComboBox style definition follows... -->
```

By sequentially drilling down into the complex control style tree, using nested Style.Resources, I am able to target specific aspects of a control style, without needing the entire style definition.

The xaml code above successfully drills all the way down to the "Track"... I can change things like the margin, cursor, etc. of the Track.  But, I just can't seem to get that last step to the Thumb.  Also, I can't seem to access the Repeat buttons, which should be at the same level (in the object tree) as the Track.

Looking at the style template for ScrollBars seems to show that the object tree is ScrollBar->Track->Thumb... but I seem to be missing something?

Any ideas on how to get access to the Thumb color?

Answer (score 0):

The default style for the `ScrollBar` sets the `Style` property of the `Thumb` explicitly in the `Track`:

```
<Track x:Name="PART_Track" ...>
    ...
    <Track.Thumb>
        <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumbVertical}"/>
    </Track.Thumb>
</Track>
```

This means that your implicit `Thumb` style won't be applied.

So you will have to define a custom complete `ControlTemplate` for the `ScrollBar` to be able to modify the style/template of the `Thumb`.

Alternatively, you may consider to look it up in the visual tree at runtime and set any of its properties programmatically.

Comment: Ok.  Alternatively... is there a way to override the "ScrollBarThumbVertical" resource so that when it explicitly calls it, it get's my modified style instead of the built-in style?

Comment: No, I am afraid not, the `ScrollBarThumbVertical` resource is resolved when the style/template is applied so you need to define the `Thumb` element yourself to set the `Style` property of if to something else.

Comment: Ok... thanks.  My only obstacle now is that the usual "Edit -> Copy Template" option is unavailable for ScrollViewer controls.  Some kind of Visual Studio bug (it's grayed out).  So, I am struggling getting a complete XAML code so that I can custom style ComboBox.  To do so, I think I need ComboBox, ComboBox Items Container, ScrollViewer, and ScrollBar (which is where Thumb is defined).  So, I can make copies of 3 out of the 4... but can't figure out where to get the XAML for ScrollViewer.

Comment: It's the `ScrollBar` template that you should edit so right-click on a `ScrollBar` and choose Edit Template->Edit a Copy.